# Проверка существования записи в БД

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Есть ли в symfony/doctrine готовый интрумент, который возвращает булевое значение о наличии идентификатора в таблице? Ну типа:

```
if($somevar->checkExists($id))
{
   //to do
}
```

Comment: `Репозиторий сущности - find()`

Comment: @u_mulder я так и делаю, просто по сути ето обьект создает что бы проверить. Я думал есть что то менее ресурсоемкое.

Comment: Ну если только в репозитории написать свой метод который вернет `getSingleScalarValue` например.

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить количество записей по критерию:

```
<?php
// Check there is no user with nickname
$availableNickname = 0 === $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->count(['nickname' => 'nonexistent']);
```

Если кол-во больше нуля, то запись присутствует [документация](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)